# zkCli.sh connect to server on SSL port 2281

Tags: java, ssl

We are facing issue in connecting to Zookeeper server on port(secureport) 2281,
trying with
zkCli.sh -server localhost:2281
how to connect to zk over SSL

```
      at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1262) [zookeeper-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
2020-12-01T15:59:48.672+0000 [myid:localhost:2281] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2281):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1154] - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2281.
2020-12-01T15:59:48.672+0000 [myid:localhost:2281] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2281):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1156] - SASL config status: Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2020-12-01T15:59:48.673+0000 [myid:localhost:2281] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2281):ClientCnxn$SendThread@986] - Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:55104, server: localhost/127.0.0.1:2281
2020-12-01T15:59:48.675+0000 [myid:localhost:2281] - WARN  [main-SendThread(localhost:2281):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1272] - Session 0x0 for sever localhost/127.0.0.1:2281, Closing socket connection. Attempting reconnect except it is a SessionExpiredException.
org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:75) ~[zookeeper-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:348) ~[zookeeper-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1262) [zookeeper-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
2020-12-01T15:59:50.562+0000 [myid:localhost:2281] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2281):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1154] - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2281.
2020-12-01T15:59:50.562+0000 [myid:localhost:2281] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2281):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1156] - SASL config status: Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2020-12-01T15:59:50.563+0000 [myid:localhost:2281] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2281):ClientCnxn$SendThread@986] - Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:55118, server: localhost/127.0.0.1:2281
2020-12-01T15:59:50.565+0000 [myid:localhost:2281] - WARN  [main-SendThread(localhost:2281):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1272] - Session 0x0 for sever localhost/127.0.0.1:2281, Closing socket connection. Attempting reconnect except it is a SessionExpiredException.
org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:75) ~[zookeeper-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:348) ~[zookeeper-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1262) [zookeeper-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
2020-12-01T15:59:52.068+0000 [myid:localhost:2281] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2281):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1154] - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2281.
2020-12-01T15:59:52.068+0000 [myid:localhost:2281] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2281):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1156] - SASL config status: Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2020-12-01T15:59:52.069+0000 [myid:localhost:2281] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2281):ClientCnxn$SendThread@986] - Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:55140, server: localhost/127.0.0.1:2281
2020-12-01T15:59:52.071+0000 [myid:localhost:2281] - WARN  [main-SendThread(localhost:2281):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1272] - Session 0x0 for sever localhost/127.0.0.1:2281, Closing socket connection. Attempting reconnect except it is a SessionExpiredException.
org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:75) ~[zookeeper-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:348) ~[zookeeper-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1262) [zookeeper-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
```

server configuration

```
  authProvider.loadableX509=com.mom.generic.conn.authentication.AuthenticationLoader
  ssl.authProvider=loadableX509
  serverCnxnFactory=org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory
  sslQuorumReloadCertFiles=true
  secureClientPort=2281
  sslQuorum=false
  portUnification=true
  ssl.quorum.clientAuth=need
  ssl.quorum.hostnameVerification=true
  ssl.quorum.keyStore.location=/etc/zookeeper/secrets/cert.pem
  ssl.quorum.trustStore.location=/run/zookeeper/secrets/tlsca/cacertpem
  ssl.trustStore.location=/run/zookeeper/secrets/client_ca/clientca.pem
  ssl.keyStore.location=/etc/zookeeper/secrets/cert.pem
  ssl.clientAuth=need
```

would need help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You have `ssl.clientAuth` set to `need`. If that is the case, you will have to provide the ZK client config data via a config file using `bin/zkCli.sh -client-configuration client.conf -server localhost:2281` And have the client cert data (truststore/keystore) mentioned along with the server certs to trust in `client.conf`. You can even have the `CLIENT_JVMARGS` set as environment variable as explained in this [ZooKeeper SSL Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/ZooKeeper+SSL+User+Guide)

A quick way to test connectivity to ZK over TLS would be to `disable` `ssl.clientAuth` on the server side and run a 4 letter word command such as `srvr`, `stat`, or `mntr` with `nc` as:

`echo mntr | nc --ssl localhost:2281`

This will tell you if TLS is setup correctly on the server side and you can connect to the `securePort`.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to disable ssl.clientAuth
this command still works (note remove ":")
`echo mntr | nc --ssl localhost 2281`
`echo ruok | nc --ssl localhost 2281` returns imok too.

`/etc/zookeeper/secrets/cert.pem`. -- this line seems suspicious. generally you need a jks file form with both cert and key pem entries. seems like you only provide cert.pem and is this a combo file with both cert.pem and key.pem? anyway what worked for me is adding my cert.pem and key.pem to java keystore with a password and using it.
for ex: Step1 is to generate a pkcs12 and then generate a jks file from this

```
sudo openssl pkcs12 -export -in ${LOCATION_URL}/${CERTS_FOLDER}/cert.pem -inkey ${LOCATION_URL}/${KEYS_FOLDER}/key.pem -name serverpkcs12 -password pass:password > serverpkcs12.p12`

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore serverpkcs12.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore zkkeystore.jks -srcstorepass password -deststorepass password`
move zkkeystore.jks to /tmp
ssl.quorum.keyStore.location=/tmp/zkkeystore.jks
ssl.quorum.keyStore.password=password
ssl.keyStore.location=/tmp/zkkeystore.jks
ssl.keyStore.password=password
```

one more suggestion just set the host verification to false
on the client side and test it. once it starts working then enable it.